# XCUITest Drag cross multiple elements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest

I want to test gesture pattern

It's need drag and hold cross multiple elements

But when I use `press(forDuration: Int, thenDragTo: XCUIElement)`

it would drop touch when drag to element

Is there any way to test this case?

The scenario that I want to do is:

1. Press and hold element 1
2. hold and drag cross element 2 -> element 3 -> ....
3. drop

Answer (score 0):

You have the right function, but you need to add the `thenHoldForDuration` parameter. See [press(forDuration:thenDragTo:withVelocity:thenHoldForDuration:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/3551693-press).

The problem you might face is XCUITest is synchronous. If you need to assert something while the press is held, you're out of luck; the code will not proceed until the duration is reached and the press is released.

Comment: I don't need to assert something while press is held, I just want to hold and cross multiple elements, and drop in the end

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for a multi-point drag prior to drop. This does not exist, sorry.